# How to fix doubly linked nodes not correctly linking?

Tags: c

My doubly linked list is a deck of cards.  I have initialized them correctly but they are not connecting.  The left header points to NULL in both directions and while my right header's previous pointer points to the previous card, that card's previous pointer points to NULL.  How can I connect them?  I'm pretty sure it's not a difficult solution but I just can't figure it out for some reason.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RAND_MAX 51

typedef struct card_s {
char suit;
int face;
struct card_s *next, *previous;
}card;

void addcard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr, int i, char c) {
card *temp;
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card)); 
temp->face = i;
temp->suit = c;
if (*hl == NULL) {
    temp->previous = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    *hl = temp;
    *hr = temp;
}
else if (p == NULL) {
    p = calloc(1, sizeof(card));
    temp->previous = p;
    temp->next = NULL;
    p->next = temp;
    *hr = temp;
}
else {
    temp->next = p->next;
    temp->previous = p;
    p->next = temp;
    temp->next->previous = temp;
}
}

void delectecard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr) {
if (p == *hl) {
    *hl = p->next;
}
else {
    p->previous->next = p->next;
}
if (p == *hr) {
    *hr = p->previous;
}
else {
    p->next->previous = p->previous;
}
free(p);
}
void createdeck(card *p, card **hl, card **hr) {
int i = 1;
int j;
while (i <= 13) {
    j = 1;
    while (j <= 4) {
        if (j == 1) {
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'S');
        }
        if (j == 2) {
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'H');
        }
        if (j == 3) {
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'D');
        }
        if (j == 4) {
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'C');
        }j++;
    }
    i++;
}
}
void printdeck(card *currentNode) {
while (currentNode != NULL) {
    printf("Face: %d, Suit: %c\n", currentNode->face, currentNode- 
 >suit);
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
}
 int main(void) {
card *headl = NULL, *headr = NULL;
createdeck(headr, &headl, &headr);
printdeck(headl);
 }
```

Comment: From `main` you pass NULL as the first parameter to `createdeck`. And `createdeck` passes NULL as the first parameter to `addcard`. So unless I missed something, `p` is always NULL in `addcard`.

Comment: So how does that affect the linking?  It's always going to be the second to last card but should that affect the previous node pointer?

Comment: What is the purpose of a left and right head? Are you trying to end up with a doubly-linked list or a binary tree?

Comment: a doubly linked list, I used some of this off of the professor's notes, he had both heads.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I expect that's `head` and `tail` so you can scan the list and/or insert items starting from either end.

Comment: @gavincloud If `p` is always NULL, then you'll definitely never reach the `else` block. That can't be good. I'm not sure what you intended there.

Comment: @user3386109 My else is an adaptation of the professor's notes, I could cut it out I think.  I just want my nodes to connect properly.

Comment: @gavincloud: Is it the case that one of these head nodes is intended to be the tail node? Because you are not maintaining a tail link either in FIFO or LIFO order.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, my headr node should be the tail node.

Comment: Then, if you are inserting at the tail, the tail node pointer has to be reassigned to the new node when it is added, and the head and tail nodes should refer to each other in one order or another, either LIFO or FIFO. Start with that.